# Override code-first naming convention for many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 2 entities with a many-to-many relationship that do not follow code-first naming convention, I have to find a way to override that.

First entity :

```
public class User  
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rule> { get; set; }
}
```

Second entity :

```
public class Rule  
{
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> { get; set; }
}
```

I have a table in between of those 2 with the classic mapping (name is `UserRule` with a composite primary key made of 2 colums (`UserId, RuleId`) with corresponding foreign keys)

the dbcontext I use is this one :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; private set; }
    public IDbSet<Rule> Rules { get; private set; }

    private const string ConnectionStringName = "connectionstring";

    public DataContext() : base(ConnectionStringName)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        Rules = Set<Rule>();
        Users = Set<User>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // use this to disable database migrations and not use metadata inside database
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);

        // setup MaestroAgentConfig to its table
        builder.Configurations.Add(new UserTable());

        // setup SecurityRule to its table
        builder.Configurations.Add(new RuleTable());

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The mapping tables I have are :

```
public class UserTable : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserProfileTable()
    {
        Property(x => x.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasMany(x => x.SecurityRules)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserProfiles)
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.MapRightKey("UserId");
                map.MapRightKey("RuleId");
                map.ToTable("UserRule");
            });
        ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

and :

```
public class RuleTable : EntityTypeConfiguration<Rule>
{
    public RuleTable()
    {
        Property(x => x.RuleId).HasColumnName("RuleId").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasKey(x => x.RuleId);
        ToTable("Rule");
    }
}
```

Yet when EF query the DB it looks like this :

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    { other fields }
FROM 
    [dbo].[UserProfile] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'EMYODE\erick.girard'
```

and :

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[RuleId] AS [RuleId], 
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM  
    [dbo].[UserRule] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Rule] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RuleId] = [Extent2].[RuleId]
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[User_UserId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=37
```

Now on the 2nd request I can't find a way to use "`UserId`" only on the `UserRule` table

How can I manage to do this ?

(Edit)
I tried removing the following 3 conventions but so far it didn't change anything:

```
builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
builder.Conventions.Remove<NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
builder.Conventions.Remove<TypeNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code an exact copy, or pseudo code?

Pasting in your code exactly, I got the same result -

However, you're mapping the right part of the mapping table twice:

```
map.MapRightKey("UserId");
map.MapRightKey("RuleId");
```

I changed the top command to map to the left key

```
map.MapLeftKey("UserId");
map.MapRightKey("RuleId");
```

and fixed it for me.

Comment: oh my ... how dumb I am today ... that fixed it !